A Colorful Explosion
What is the process to get the final answer?


Brilliant puzzle!

How do we get to the answer?

 By TILING

Like so...

 


 


 


 


 


 


Nicely solved. Out of interest, which software did you choose to use for the images?

@Stiv I'm not the answerer, but it's fairly easy with any image editor, even Paint.

@Stiv, if interested, I created it with Paint as well :)

@Lezzup Ha, I could tell from the colour palette it was a Paint creation! :) Just wondering what folks default to for their image editor of choice when solving...

@stiv I used GIMP for this. Imo, Krita is better, but I'm stuck in old ways.

For solving this, seems like it would be annoying to use paint. Select by color is a little too nice.

Is it just me or is that first image quite an optical illusion? As I scroll down/up it seems to expand/contract.

Wrap-up:  The Making Of A Colorful Explosion
This is not a solution to the puzzle, but provides notes from its poser. This type of answer has been approved by the community.
Caution: This post may contain spoilers.

Although this puzzle is relatively easy, it's a great way to hide some images or shapes. It works with every letter, image or symbol, as long as it has no holes in it. That's the reason I choose a word that didn't contain letters like A, B, O or P.
I would like to share the simple steps to create these shapes yourself.
Let's say you want to create a shape that hide a nice turtle:


Step 1. convert the image to only an outline of the image, and copy it once to the right:


Step 2 copy both images simultaneously to the bottom to preserve the distances.


Step 3 draw one squiggly line horizontal between the two upper turtles, and one squiggly line vertical between the two turtles to the left.


Step 4 copy both lines to the other turtles.


Step 5 draw a line on the outline of each turtle only on the inside.


Step 6 remove the other outlines of the turtles, and you have your final shape :)




I had guessed you: 1. drew the shape in the middle and a big bounding box around it. 2. made four wigglies coming out of it in the four directions until they hit the bounding box. 3. Copy and paste the thing you made 3 more times and line them up.

Visibility depends on browser. Click on pictures.
